# How can I create template for login and register page separately?

Tags: 8

In drupal 8 how can I create template for login and register sections separately ?

Comment: Anyone can answer to me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "section"? Region? Block? Form?

Comment: Page . or ech one I want create page with custom sections and fields